# Use column from temp table that is populated by stored proc

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, temp-tables

I know this is wrong and won't work but here's an idea of what I'm trying to do.

I would just join the table that the [GetFinalCountByGroupId] sp is using internally but I don't want to because the table it uses has some large varbinary data. Of course the sp is still querying it so maybe it is just as good performance wise as a join rather than a sp call. Either way I'm curious if I can get this to work first - if not I'll just try a join. Anyway, here's some code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetFinalRequests]
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON
DECLARE @FinalTable TABLE
(
  FinalCount TINYINT
)
INSERT INTO @FinalTable
EXEC [dbo].[GetFinalCountByGroupId] [GroupId]

SELECT [Id]
      ,[GroupId]
      ,[SubmitBy]
      ,[InUse]
  FROM [dbo].[Requests]
  WHERE [InUse] = 1
  AND @FinalTable.FinalCount > 0
END
```

edit: here is the result of executing this...
**Must declare the scalar variable "@FinalTable".**

Comment: You dont know if your procedure will work...did you try to execute it?

Comment: Im not the one that downvoted you ;)

Comment: Are you sure that is the real procedure?   Because FinalExecutedTable is nowhere in it.

Comment: edited. typo......anyone want to answer my question? ;)

Comment: Another typo?  -  @Finalable

Comment: Tough crowd tonight!

Comment: How can you expect help with syntax if you don't post the actual syntax?

Comment: Anyone care to explain what makes this question worthy of all the down votes?  I really would like an explanation so I can actually learn from this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a syntax error here:

```
SELECT [Id]
      ,[GroupId]
      ,[SubmitBy]
      ,[InUse]
FROM [dbo].[Requests]
WHERE [InUse] = 1
  AND @FinalTable.FinalCount > 0
```

You can not access `FinalCount` column like that in `SQL`.
I don't know the purpose of the temp table but just to make it work:

```
SELECT [Id]
      ,[GroupId]
      ,[SubmitBy]
      ,[InUse]
FROM [dbo].[Requests]
WHERE [InUse] = 1
  AND (select sum(FinalCount) from @FinalTable) > 0
```

Comment: I can create the stored proc with this code - but executing it results in: 
    Error converting data type nvarchar to uniqueidentifier.
Is there a conversion I need to do with the passed in parameter or something?

Answer (score 0):

Ok - I abandoned this and just did a join:

```
SELECT [Id]
      ,r.[GroupId]
      ,[SubmitBy]
      ,[InUse]
FROM [dbo].[Requests] r
JOIN [dbo].[AgreementDocuments] d
  ON r.[GroupId] = d.[GroupId]
WHERE r.[InUse] = 1
AND d.[Final] = 1
```